# Weak NSArray of UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a custom segue which takes an array of UIViews to manipulate/animate, however, the array of UIViews leads to a retain cycle.

What’s the best way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given too many details about your implementation, so my first suggestion would be to look into [NSPointerArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html).

```
NSPointerArray *array = [NSPointerArray weakObjectsPointerArray];
[array addPointer:yourView];
```

However, depending on what the actual problem is, you might be able do a refactor such that it doesn't need a weak pointer array. If you can do this, it would be better, as `NSPointerArray` is more expensive than a regular array.

Comment: Should have mentioned, when I dismiss a `UIViewController` they don’t get removed from memory because of the retain cycle